# CTRL + C and keyword key C , both events work at same time JavaScript || Jquery

Tags: javascript, keyboard

As i am creating keyword shortcut to my website, like by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> key, it redirects me to any  page I want.

But the problem occur that when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> combination, it copies text for me, but it also redirects me to other page.

I tried to create a small demo:

```js
 document.onkeyup = function(e) {
     var e = e || window.event; 
    if ((e.which == 67)) {
        alert("C key is pressed");
    }else if ((e.ctrlKey) && (e.which == 67)) {
        alert("Text Copied");
    } 
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
h5{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weigt:bold;
}
```

```html
<h5>Creating Shortcut for Website</h5>
<p>By clicking on <q>C</q> key on Keyboard, your page will reload</p>
```

Hope you will understand.

Thanks for you attendance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code such that checking for <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> come before checking for the redirection key.

Also, note that `KeyboardEvent#which` is deprecated, so you should use `KeyboardEvent#key` instead:

```js
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event; 
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'c') {
        alert("Text copied");
    }else if (e.key === 'c') {
        alert("C key is pressed");
    }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
h5{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weigt:bold;
}
```

```html
<h5>Creating Shortcut for Website</h5>
<p>By clicking on <q>C</q> key on Keyboard, your page will reload</p>
```

However, that won't work always.

If you do the following:

```
Ctrl down
C down
C up
Ctrl up
```

...then it will work, but if the sequence is (which would also trigger a copy operation):

```
Ctrl down
C down
Ctrl up
C up
```

...then it won't.

Why?

The problem is the `keyup` event itself. As the event object represents the keyboard state at the time when the event is emitted, `keyup` checks for modifier keys **when <kbd>C</kbd> is *released***.

However, since modifier keys usually have to be pressed *before* the key they modify, checks should happen at the time when the keys are *pressed down*.

So, you'll have to use the `keydown` event instead:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event; 
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'c') {
        alert("Text copied");
    }else if (e.key === 'c') {
        alert("C key is pressed");
    }
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
h5{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weigt:bold;
}
```

```html
<h5>Creating Shortcut for Website</h5>
<p>By clicking on <q>C</q> key on Keyboard, your page will reload</p>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, it works but there is another problem, suppose that   there is "Shift+C" in place of  "CTRL+C" in the code , and if i press  "CTRL + C"  key  it  do  what it does but also show me the result of  "C"  key.

Comment: @ShubhamRawat You have to perform both actions on `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: No i don't want to perform both action on  "CTRL+C" , both action perform automatically.  I just shared a codepen link .  At that code, if you press "C" Key it work  , but when i pressed "CTRL+C" it also give result of "C" key. https://codepen.io/Shbham07/pen/rNOVNrB

Comment: I think I've got the problem. Even if you add a condition that filters out `Ctrl+C` (like [here](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/OJyVPgd)), it won't *always* work. It's with the `keyup` event itself. If you do the following: `Ctrl` down, `C` down, `C` up, `Ctrl` up; it will work. However, `Ctrl` down, `C` down, `Ctrl` up, `C` up; which would also trigger a copy operation, won't. It's because `keyup` checks for `Ctrl` when `C` is *released*. So I recommend the `keydown` event instead: https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/qBOdEPP

Comment: i understood the reason, why this happening thank you so much  for help me.